# YouCompleteMe unavailable: module 'collections' has no attribute 'Mapping'

Tags: vim, module, attributes, youcompleteme

Hi I have been trying to setup YouCompleteMe in vim but it don't work. I am using vim-plug. I tried around 3 different YouCompleteMe repositories but i always got the same error. I am using a Mac os and everything about vim is up to date. I tried adding scripts in .vimrc, running install.py but non of em worked. I really need Help. Here is my .vimrc script and the error [image]

Comment: Use the plugin's issue tracker/official support channels.

Comment: I totally sympathise with you. I have the same problem and I am going around in circles reading the information on the plugin's issue tracker/official support channels, following the suggestions and getting nowhere. If you find the answer I am very interested to know how to fix it.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to fix the problem is to install youcompleteme in the following way.

1. In a Terminal, run the command:

`$ sudo apt install vim-youcompleteme`

2. Next, run the command:

`$ vim-addon-manager install youcompleteme`

I got my exactly the same problem fixed a minute ago by running the above two commands, thanks to [dominoc925's youcompleteme installation instructions](https://dominoc925.blogspot.com/2019/09/installing-vim-youcompleteme-for-ubuntu.html).